# Changing learning rate of snapshotted Tensorflow Optimizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

As the question says...is there any way to change the learning rate of an Optimizer object? So say I continue some training procedure using a snapshot of a prior model, but since creating that snapshot, I realise that my model is skipping round the energy landscape instead of settling down and generating some pretty output. Is there any way to load in the Optimizer object and setting a new learning rate post-hoc?

There's the object field _lr in the python memory space and _lr_t (in the tf memory space) that are numerically equal, however assigning to _lr doesn't change the value of _lr_t. Presumably it hence does not affect computions on the graph. Sooo, how can that learning rate be changed? Do I have to construct a new Optimizer object that then must be also attached to the network output? And just ignore the "old" Optimizer object restored from the snapshot?

If so, that seems a bit wasteful in terms of memory, and messy in terms of code, rather than just providing some setters.

Comment: What do you mean by "restored from the snapshot"? The snapshot just stores variables, not the graph, you do build the graph again yourself before loading the snapshot ... and you can just use a different learning rate when building that graph.

Comment: Yeah I am re-building the graph, but lets make it concrete. I'm using an AdamOptimizer. I build my graph in exactly the same way as the (variable) snapshot expects...it's literally the same method that built the graph the first time, except I've changed the learning rate to 0.00075 instead of 0.001. I call saver.restore(sess, checkpoint_path). The AdamOptimizer object now has an _lr of 0.001. That is, the old learning rate was restored. Now how can I change that learning rate?

Comment: Usually you'd only save and restore the variables that you want, like trainable vars and things like the global step - it seems you save/restore everything?

Comment: Are you sure that `opt._lr` returns the old learning rate `0.001`? This is not normal behavior at all, I think there is a bug in your code.